# More efficient regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm parsing about 200,000 documents (~1-3gb each) to remove all non-alphanumeric characters using regex and match the input format for some ancient piece of code. Each word/number needs to be separated by an `_`.

I've split them into separate parts so it works but I've been trying unsuccessfully to combine the expressions into one.

How can I combine the pieces together?

What are the considerations of combining the expression?

```
def clean_document(raw_input):
    no_more_etf = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', raw_input)
    no_more_non_utf = re.sub(r'[\000-\011\013-\037]', '', no_more_etf)
    no_more_spaces = re.sub('\s+', '_', no_more_non_utf.strip())
    almost_there = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '_', no_more_spaces)
    clean_string = almost_there.lower()
    return clean_string
```

Samples string:
`'"where is the Vehicles  我是一群隨機人物 "countries"=>"35,214" "refinement"=>"3"  我的书在哪里"I\'m a dirty array object"=>"" "category_ids"=>"2,5,7,8"  "data_size_units"=>"", "delivery_formats"=>"1,4"  "delivery_® ® ®methods"=>"1,2", "price_currencies"=>"1" , "trial_currencies"=>"1", "categories"=>"2,10 ,19", "Delivery_growth_units ® ® ®"=>"", "trial_duration_units"=>"6",  私の本はどこですか "collection_time_units"=>"", "strategies"=>"2,3 , 4,6", "processing_time_units"=>"", "delivery_frequency_units" =>"", "subscription_duration_units "=>"6" ® ® ® ģ ģ ģ - GPS Place-Visits for Delivery Vehicles'`

Comment: Those `re.sub`s with the same replacement patterns usually can be ORed. `re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', raw_input)` and `re.sub(r'[\000-\011\013-\037]', '', no_more_etf)` can be written as `re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+|[\000-\011\013-\037]+', '', raw_input)`. Also, `'[^0-9a-zA-Z]+'` matches whitespaces, so your `no_more_spaces = re.sub('\s+', '_', no_more_non_utf.strip())` is redundant.

Comment: You may rewrite is as `def clean_document(raw_input): return re.sub(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '_', re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+|[\000-\011\013-\037]+', '', raw_input.strip().lower()))`

Comment: Ah ok, so my mistake was the syntax and trying to do two different substitutions using one combined pattern.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform all these substitutions (except the .strip()) using the translate method of standard strings  (see string.translate and string.maketrans https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html ).

If you don't want to use translate, you would benefit from preparing compiled versions of the substitution patterns outside of the function and using the compiled versions in your re.sub() calls.   Also using a single re.sub() instead of multiple ones will also make things faster.